# Swift: GM Xcode 6.1 And AFNetworking AFJSONResponseSerializer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, afnetworking-2

Before installing GM Xcode 6.1 the below code is working fine. However after installing Xcode 6.1, I'm getting error:

[image]

I tried this, and the error was really nice.
[image]

Any idea? I haven't read the release note yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess, but try cleaning the project or wiping your `DerivedData` directory.

```
let x = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
```

Works fine for me in Xcode 6.1 GM.

Is `AFJSONResponseSerializer` in the bridging header btw?

Comment: This `let x = AFJSONResponseSerializer()` worked. Why?

Comment: I discovered that Swift has an amazing feature called **error obfuscation**. If there's an error, it complains about another unrelated error somewhere else which isn't actually true just to annoy you. -- I don't know why it's doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using explicit casting. Try this code:

```
let foo = AFJSONResponseSerializer() as AFJSONResponseSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put nil you get the data in a format that sent the server, or you will have to strictly specify that you expect to receive

try this code

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil
```

Comment: Please explain why this code is a solution to the problem. While it may work, understand why it works is a valuable piece of information for other readers.

Comment: That's good, thanks. Edit your answer to include this information. It will be clearer than burying it in a comment.